# Need Sunday as the first day of the week

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, python-datetime

I would like Sunday to be 0, but when using the datetime weeday methods it's 6:

```
datetime(2013, 6, 9, 11, 59, 59, 1).weekday()  # this returns 6
```

My locale is: "en_US.UTF-8" so Sunday *should* be 0 (when I run 'locale day' at bash prompt, it correctly shows 'Sunday' as first day of the week).

```
$ locale day
Sunday;Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday;Thursday;Friday;Saturday
```

How can I get python to show Sunday as the first day of the week?

*(I'm using a pandas timeseries and calling `.date` to get the datetimes.)*

Comment: First, bash isn't the same as python.  Second, what use case do you see having the ordinal number of the week as useful?  Perhaps some context would help answer your question.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think you have spent enough time fleshing out your question. It's very pandas light, and just reads like you care about datetimes. Are you asking about pandas rather than datetime really?

Comment: Depending of what you are trying to do `calendar` package might help. There you can configure which day is the first one of the week, and more...

Answer (score 16):

Try this :

```
(datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 9, 11, 59, 59, 1).weekday() + 1) % 7
```

Comment: Surely +1 rather than -6 :), also you're missing a paren

Comment: Yep, shame on me ! ;-) Thanks for the patch ! (-6 was also working, but not in very logical way, I agree...)

Comment: this seems to be working:                                   weeks = df22.date.map(lambda x: x.week if x.dayofweek == 6 else x.week -1 )

Answer (score 2):

Rather than going via date (creating datetime objects) use the dayofweek attribute (which will be faster):

```
In [1]: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2013', periods=72, freq='D')

In [2]: (rng.dayofweek + 1 ) % 7
Out[2]:
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3,
       4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
       6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0,
       1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

You could make this an attribute:

```
In [3]: rng.my_dayofweek = (rng.dayofweek + 1 ) % 7
```

Similarly you could calculate your own week:

```
In [4]: rng.my_week = rng.map(lambda x: x.week if x.dayofweek else x.week - 1)
```

Which would then be available to you as attributes.

.

The datetime.date `weekday` method is not locale specific, it's hardcoded (here's its docstring):

> Return the day of the week represented by the date.
>   `Monday == 0 ... Sunday == 6`

Comment: is it possible to change python's default weekdays so that Sunday == 0?

Comment: Not in datetime.dates weekday method. In pandas you could write your own easily, in fact will update question.